# probability question , coins in a box

Tags: probability

imagine we have 3 boxes A , B , C

in two of them there is only a coin, but in the other there are 3 coins

so everytime i pick a box i have

$ P(1 coin)= 2/3 $ $ P(3 coins)= 1/3 $

then i have two types of outcome imagine i pick 'x' times for x big

what would be the function (approximately) $ N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{x}a(n) $

where $ N(x) $ is the number of coins after x outcomes and $ a(n)= 1,3 $ depending of the probability is the number of coins obtained in every pick

Comment: What's the question?  What you have written is certainly not a function.  It's a random variable...did you want it's expected value?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the expected number of coins, use the linearity of expectation.  What is the expected value of the number of coins on one trial?

If you want the probability distribution, it is binomial.